# Python SMTP Pcap Generator

Tags: python, pcap

I need to generate network traffic with a specific SMTP/MIME message in place. Does Python have any libraries that support the ability to generate a pcap file containing the particular information I am looking for?

Comment: There's [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), there's [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) and there's [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/). I think a combination of the first two or the last two will allow you to generate the packet and modify the capture file.

Comment: FTR, Scapy even has `wrpcap/PcapWriter` if you want to write the pcaps